# Positioning overlapped view in Android

Tags: android, xml, position

Simply - how place one view on the top of another view (which can shrink) in the strictly defined place regardless of screen resolution and density?

Example - place TextView on the top of image always on pyramides. When I am using margins (Frame or Relative layout) with dp units they fail on different screen size :(

[image: explaination]

## XML

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
      android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
When I am using margins (Frame or Relative layout) with dp units they fail on different screen size
```

yes they will always fail due to that other devices has different dp.

**solution:**

you can always use the `values` folder of your `res` folder where you put your values to the `dimens.xml`so your margin will always change depending on the device you are testing.

Comment: I thought there is simpler solution to maintain position on all screens like linearlayout with weights

Comment: @user1112008 but positioning to your textView to the specified location will be hard without specifying the margin

Comment: @user1112008 also you cant overlap views using linearlayout

Comment: only if I could drop LinearLayout on the top op ImageView with same size I could use few views inside with weights but when I do match_parent the parent view is taking all space (doesnt wrap imageview content)

Comment: @user1112008 you can create linear layout but instead of using imageview as background you can put the image to the linearlayout background and add your textview

Comment: Um, that went better than expected, I didn't even think about it. It is working, Thanks!